# canvas ping pong sparkles

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

Im trying to add sparks to my basic ping pong game. The sparkels should be added whenever the ball hits the paddle. I am creating the sparks as object with

```
function create_sparks(x, y, m) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.r = 1,2;
    this.vx = -1.5 + Math.random() * 3;
    this.vy = m * Math.random() * 1.5;
}
```

im creating them like this

```
if (flag == 1) {
        for (var j = 0; j < 20; j++) {

            particles.push(new create_sparks(spark.x, spark.y, mult));
        }
    }
    emitspark();
    flag = 0;
```

the flag is 1 when the ball hits the puddle , spark.x and spark.y are the source of the ball (where it hits the puddle) and finaly im animating them like this

```
function emitspark() {
    for (var i = 0; i < particles.length; i++) {
        var p = particles[i];
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.fillStyle = "white";
        if (p.r > 0) {
            ctx.arc(p.x, p.y, p.r, 0, Math.Pi * 2);
        }
        ctx.fill();
        p.x+=p.vx;
        p.y+=p.vy;
        p.r=Math.max(p.r-0.05,0.0);
    }
}
```

the problem is , the sparks wont show up , nor the code throws any error and works fine (just without sparks) did i overlooked something? [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Trolstover/jcp2e4kx/3/)
is the demo

Comment: try remembering to close the path after each iteration ctx.closePath();

Comment: You are trying to access `ball.h`, but `ball` doesn't have any variable `h` set for it.

Comment: drawning of ball works fine , im talking about sparks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The major problem is ball.h being undefined - it generates a NaN value for spark.y values.

```
ball = {
    x: 50,
    y: 50,
    r: 5,
    h: 10, // < ---- NEW
    c: "white",
    vx: 4,
    vy: 8,

    // Function for drawing ball on canvas
    draw: function () {
       ctx.beginPath();
       ctx.fillStyle = this.c;
       ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.r, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
       ctx.fill();
       update();
    }
};
```

fixes this.  I also changed emitspark() whilst exploring the code. Simplify as you will but this version worked for me:

```
function emitspark() {
    for (var i = 0; i < particles.length; i++) {
        var p = particles[i];
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(p.x, p.y, p.r, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
            ctx.lineWidth = 15;
            ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
            ctx.fillStyle="white";
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.stroke();
        p.x+=p.vx;
        p.y+=p.vy;
        p.r=Math.max(p.r-0.05,0.0);
    }
}
```

Finally I suggest setting the particle array length to zero once the spark effect is over to prevent the array getting longer and longer. Zero radius sparks are still being processed - one assumes the context arc method is simply not creating a path for them. But nice sparkles!